# Inheriting from a non-templated class that has a templated constructor - how to resolve ambiguity?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Let's say we have a class, MyParent:

```
class MyParent
{
public:
  template<namespace T>
  MyParent()
  {
    T* Something;
  }
};
```

And a derived class, which uses this constructor:

```
class MyDerived : public MyParent
{
public:
  MyDerived()
  : MyParent<int>()
  {
  }
};
```

Then I get a compiling error, because there's ambiguity. The compiler thinks that the ***int*** is a template argument to the class, not the constructor.

How do I specify that I want the ***int*** to be an argument to the constructor?

Comment: Does T need to be hidden in the implementation of the constructor? Shouldn't there be an argument to the constructor of type T?

Comment: There does not NEED to be. But it would make things easy if therewere.

Comment: is that template< typename T > you mean?  (Never saw the <namespace T> construct...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. From the standard section 14.8.1  Explicit template argument, it notes:

> [Note: because  the explicit template argument list follows the function template name, and because conversion member  function  templates and  constructor  member function templates are called without using a
>     function name, there is no way to provide an explicit  template  argument list for these function templates.  ]

As noted in the comments, you would need to have the constructor take a parameter of type `T` (or `const T &`), and then have `MyDerived` call `MyParent::MyParent` with a paremeter of type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that your question is not particular to inheritance. Given your code example, you cannot instantiate `MyParent` at all, either because it doesn't accept a template argument list or because it has no default constructor.

In order to instantiate `MyParent` with a constructor template, you need to provide some way for the compiler to know the template argument, and you can't do that with a no-argument constructor. You need to give `MyParent`'s constructor a parameter. Here's an example based on [code from Alf P. Steinbach](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t545918-template-default-constructor-possible.html):

```
template <typename T>
struct UseMethodsOf {};

class MyParent
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  MyParent(UseMethodsOf<T>)
  {
    T* Something;
  }
};

class MyDerived: public MyParent
{
public:
  MyDerived()
  : MyParent(UseMethodsOf<int>())
  {
  }
};
```

Comment: Now you too make it as complete as it can be. One gives me the true answer, the other gives me the workaround. Thanks to you both!